# bar plot number of 0s in a dataframe. Fill based on group

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, statistics, bar-chart

I have this dataset

```
structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2"), Year = c("2017", 
"2017", "2014", "2014", "2016", "2014"), First = c("Ricardo", 
"Ricardo", "David", "Johnson", "Rodney", "Duron"), Last = c("Allen", 
"Allen", "Amerson", "Bademosi", "McLeod", "Harmon"), Team = c("ATL", 
"ATL", "OAK", "NE", "PHI", "NE"), Week = c(4, 4, 7, 10, 8, 8), 
    mean_tackles = c(4, 4, 4.33333333333333, 1, 7.33333333333333, 
    1.75), mean_PassesDefended = c(0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 
    0.666666666666667, 0), mean_int = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0), 
    mean_fumbles = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0), Group = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Concussed", "Controls", 
    "Orthopedic"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Year", 
"First", "Last", "Team", "Week", "mean_tackles", "mean_PassesDefended", 
"mean_int", "mean_fumbles", "Group"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 53L, 54L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to create the following graph. Which gives me a bar graph of the number of zeroes in the dataset for the columns 7 to 10 on the x-axis. The fill is based on which Group this represents.

[image]

To my knowledge, this can't be done using the `...count...` function in ggplot since its a conditional count.

Comment: You can use `dplyr` to calculate the counts manually beforehand. `data %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(nzero_tackles = sum(mean_tackles == 0),...)`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, separate out the data wrangling from the visualization. Get the data frame in the form you want first, then plot it.
I'm not 100% sure, but I think you mean something like this?

```
zerocount.df <- exampledata.df%>%
    select(contains("mean"),Group)%>%
    group_by(Group)%>%
    summarise_all(function(x){sum(x==0)})%>%
    ungroup()%>%
    gather(metric, zerocount, mean_tackles:mean_fumbles)

ggplot(zerocount.df,aes(x=metric,y=zerocount,group=Group,fill=Group))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+theme_bw()
```

Comment: Hi Steve,

This gets me very close. I just changed the position to "stack" and it seems to give me what I need.

[See Output Here](https://imgur.com/qg1aS9b)